# Integral over Gaussian curvature (Gauss-Bonnet)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Calculate the integral $\int_{M}KdA$,

where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature and $M=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}| x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2}=1, x,y > 0\, and\,  0 < z < 2\}$.

I wan't to do this with the local Gauss-Bonnet theorem:

$\int_{\gamma(s)}k_{g}(s)ds = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha -(n-2)\pi- \int_{int(\gamma(s))}KdA$,  $\gamma(s)$ some closed simple curve.

It seems easier to consider the surface without constraints on x,y and then divide the result by 4, which is what i try to do below.

I parametrize my surface by $X(\theta,z)=(\sqrt{z^2+1}\cos\theta,\sqrt{z^2+1}\sin\theta,z)$. My $\gamma(s)$ will then be the curves $\gamma_{1}(s)$: "bottom circle", $\gamma_{2}(s)$ and $\gamma_{3}(s)$: "up and down some meridian" and finally $\gamma_{4}(s)$: "top circle"(wish I could draw a picture for this), all of which are geodesics but $\gamma_{4}(s)$.

So I try to calculate the geodesic curvature of $\gamma_{4}(s)$, which is were I run into problems.

By definition $k_{g}(s)=\langle\gamma_{4}''(s), N(\gamma_{4}(s))\times\gamma_{4}'(s)\rangle$.

My Gauss map $$N=\frac{X_{\theta} \times X_{z}}{|X_{\theta} \times X_{z}|} =\frac{(2z\sqrt(z^{2}+1)\cos\theta,2z\sqrt(z^{2}+1)\sin\theta, -2z)}{8z^{2}+4z^{4}}$$ and $\gamma_{4}(s)=(\sqrt5 \cos \dfrac{s}{\sqrt5},\sqrt5\sin \dfrac{s}{\sqrt5},2)$.

However, I cannot make sense of the composition $N(\gamma_{4}(s))$.

My questions are:

$\bf{1.}$ Is my above strategy and reasoning for solving this integral correct?

$\bf{2.}$ How to make sense of $N(\gamma_{4}(s))$?

Comment: $\gamma_4(s)$ is a point on $X$, hence corresponds to some $(\theta,z)$.

Comment: @roslavets Are Latex & typo  edits ok?

Comment: yes absolutely, thx for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS:

You are considering a surface of one sheeted hyperboloid.

There are two approaches:

First, without involving the patch purely the top non-geodesic parallel line is considered. For a surface of revolution for this top circumferential circle if   $ R_g $ is tangent length,

$$ k_g = \frac{1}{R_g} $$

In your case consider tangent,z-axis and radius. $ z =2, r= \sqrt 5 , R_g= 3 $ , so $ k_g =\dfrac13. $

Next for the patch, there are 4 corners turning $\pi/2$ at each corner and 3 geodesics between $ 0, \theta_{max} $ limits.

EDIT1:

Your approach upto what you presented is correct. Further hints.

Full circle integral curvature

$$ \int K dA  = \int \kappa_1 \kappa_2 2 \pi r dl $$

$$ = \int  \frac {d \phi}{dl} \cdot \cos \phi /r \cdot 2 \pi r dl $$

$$ 2 \pi (\sin \phi_2 - \sin \phi_1) $$

Segment of circle

$$ \theta ( \sin \phi_2 - \sin \phi_1) \tag{*} $$

The above result is useful *for patches between two parallel circles and two meridians.*

Rotation around the patch:

Three lines are geodesics so forget about them, consider only the top boundary, $ \gamma_4(s) $

$$ \int \kappa_g r d \theta = \kappa_g r \theta  $$

Hope you pull it up further.

Comment: why is $k_{g}=1/R_{g}$ for top circle?

Comment: It is locally a cone, so consider cone circle flat development.It is direct definition. $k_g$ invariant by development/bending.